# SwiftUI Multi Components Picker

Tags: swift, swiftui, picker

I try to build a multi-components picker, at the beginning I faced overlap views between the two components, and that make it hard to interact with UI, then I found ".compositingGroup()" properties which fix the problem on the simulator but on the real device I faced the same problem, then I tried many solutions like embed both pickers in "Geometry reader" and set their frame from it but its does not work too, So please if anyone has an idea how to fix this issue I glade to know it.

The Code

```
ZStack {
            background
            HStack(spacing: 16) {
                hoursPicker
                minutesPicker
            }
        }

    private var hoursPicker: some View {
        
        HStack(spacing: 8) {
            Picker("Select Hour(s)", selection: $selectedHours) {
                ForEach(hoursRange, id: \.self) {
                    Text("\($0)")
                        .toolBarViewNormalStyle()
                }
            }
            .frame(width: 32, height: 32, alignment: .center)
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8, style: .continuous))
            .compositingGroup()
            .labelsHidden()
            .pickerStyle(.wheel)
            
            Text("Hr")
                .toolBarViewNormalStyle()
        }
    }

    private var minutesPicker: some View {
        
        HStack(spacing: 8) {
            Picker("Select Minute(s)", selection: $selectedMinutes) {
                ForEach(minutesRange, id: \.self) {
                    Text("\($0)")
                        .toolBarViewNormalStyle()
                }
            }
            .frame(width: 32, height: 32, alignment: .center)
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8, style: .continuous))
            .compositingGroup()
            .labelsHidden()
            .pickerStyle(.wheel)
            
            Text("Min")
                .toolBarViewNormalStyle()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use an actual `DatePicker()` set to `.hourAndMinute`?

```
            DatePicker("Select time",
                       selection: $selectedDate,
                       displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
                .datePickerStyle(.wheel)
```

Comment: I can't use "Date Picker" because my picker let user select duration from 1 to 23 hour and from 1 to 55 min, thus I can't use "Date Picker" for that.

Comment: This appears to be a bug in iOS 15 (FB9764631). My suggestion for the moment would be to use a `.menu` picker style.

Comment: I like to use it but it will be ruin the UI and UX

Comment: Then I would use a UIViewRepresentable and put together a UIKit picker.

Comment: Do you have any example code?